Sci-fi movie with depressed android who tries to kill himself by unscrewing a bolt
I have a very vague memory of a sci-fi film I watched as a child in the 1980s (I don't know if the film was made in the 80s, it could be 70s). All I can remember was that it was a cheesy sci-fi I guess similar to Starcrash, Battle Beyond the Stars, etc. (but I haven't seen these movies but have read their plots and couldn't find what I remembered).
The scene I can remember involves an android who was depressed. He wants to die and goes to unscrew a bolt that is where his belly button should be. At the last moment he decides not to do it. Unfortunately this is all I have. Obviously, every time I look up depressed android it keeps coming up with Marvin from The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, so I'm stuck.

That darn Marvin is far too famous for his attitude... :/

"depressed robot -marvin" turns up a depressing number of results about depression and robots, but not a depressed robot... Throw "bolt" in there and you get all sorts of pages about assembly line robots for torquing bolts...

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/366498250_Bot_self-destruction_memes_are_no_laughing_matter_in_science_fiction Now, if only they had the text available without paying...

@FuzzyBoots It's probably not useful; if you google the title you can find the citations, which should include anything relevant.  It's cool to see a research paper cite tor.com and technovelgy, but there aren't any matching works cited.

The Ice Pirates (1984)
I can't find the movie online to confirm, but I remember a scene where the heroes have obtained a number of faulty and substandard robots, one of which unassembles itself by unscrewing a bolt in its belly.

I can confirm that in The Ice Pirates a robot commits suicide by unscrewing a bolt located in its belly button region. A closeup of its hand on the bolt is shown at 1:03:26. https://i.sstatic.net/TPQ9lmJj.png

Thank you so much!!!! This is the film!

@GemmaWood Please accept this answer by clicking on the check mark to the left of it. This helps us determine that the question has been answered.
